# how to combine different sizes of arrays in python into a csv as columns?

Tags: python, csv, h5py

```
coordinates = []
repeats = 24*365
grid_size = 4
for c in itertools.product(range(grid_size), range(grid_size), range(grid_size)):
    for _ in range(repeats):
        coordinates.append(list(c))
coordinates = np.array(coordinates)
print(np.array(coordinates))

a=np.array(h5py.File('/Users/Desktop/H5 Files/FIELD-3D.h5', 'r')['Zone']['TAir']['data'])
b=np.array(h5py.File('/Users/Desktop/H5 Files/FIELD-3D.h5', 'r')['Zone']['Illum']['data'])
c=np.array(h5py.File('/Users/Desktop/H5 Files/FIELD-3D.h5', 'r')['Zone']['PPD']['data'])
d=np.array(h5py.File('/Users/Desktop/H5 Files/FIELD-3D.h5', 'r')['Zone']['time']['data'])
e=np.array(coordinates)
f=np.repeat(d,365)

np.save('matrix.npy', np.array(h5py.File('/Users/Desktop/H5 Files/FIELD-3D.h5', 'r')['Zone']['TAir']['data']))
np.load('matrix.npy')

pd.DataFrame(a.flatten(order="C"), columns=["TAir"]).round(5).to_csv('TAir.csv', sep=',', index=False)
pd.DataFrame(b.flatten(order="C"), columns=["Illum"]).round(5).to_csv('Illum.csv', sep=',', index=False)
pd.DataFrame(c.flatten(order="C"), columns=["PPD"]).round(5).to_csv('PPD.csv', sep=',', index=False)
pd.DataFrame(d.flatten(order="C"), columns=["time"]).round(5).to_csv('Time.csv', sep=',', index=False)
pd.DataFrame(e).to_csv('Coordinates.csv')
output = np.column_stack((a.flatten(),b.flatten(),c.flatten(),e))
np.savetxt('test.csv',output,delimiter=',')
```

Im getting data out from a h5 file and also trying to give all the info a coordinate in a specific order.
e doesnt have the same size sadly as a/b/c but wants to visually put them next to each other in different columns if i open it in an excel file

Comment: First you create a separate CSV for each dataframe (with `.to_csv()`). Then you try to create a single array with values from all 4 arrays (`a/b/c/e`) using `np.column_stack()`. Which do you want? If you combine, how will you arrange different # of rows for `a/b/c` and `e`? Can you add an example of what the CSV file _**should**_ look like? Also, what are shape and dtype of the hdf5 datasets (e.g., `a/b/c/d`)?

Comment: Did you solve your problem? Or are you still looking for a solution?